# C program to read alternate characters from file using system calls not working in loop

Tags: c, linux, file, operating-system, system-calls

I made a program that read alternate characters from a file passed as terminal argument and print it on terminal. The program is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int fd = open(argv[1]);

    if(fd>0)
    {
        char content[1];

        while(read(fd,content,1))
        {
            write(1,content,1);
            lseek(fd,1,SEEK_CUR);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("File could not be opened.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But it is printing characters in weird pattern. But when I just used that code by repeating it one after other, it is printing alternate characters. Here is what is working:

```
    read(fd,content,1);
    write(1,content,1);
    lseek(fd,1,SEEK_CUR);

    read(fd,content,1);
    write(1,content,1);
    lseek(fd,1,SEEK_CUR);

    read(fd,content,1);
    write(1,content,1);
```

My input file:

```
abcdefgh
ijklmnopq
rstuvwxyz
```

Output I am getting:

```
ikmoq
suwy
```

By alternate characters I mean skipping 1 character.

That code is printing 3 alternate character from the file but the loop prints different characters from the second character itself. Where am I going wrong? Why is the repeating code working and loop not?

Comment: [`open` requires at least one more parameter.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) It should be `open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);`. And you should include `<fcntl.h>`. Did your compiler not warn you? Recompile with '-Wall' or '-Wmost' to enable more warnings. With the corrected `open` call and the added include, the program works for me in a simple test; it prints alternate characters from the input file.

Comment: @EricPostpischil but the programing is not giving any errors. Open is working as it is supposed to.

Comment: The program works fine if the 'open' error is corrected.

Comment: If you compiled the code shown, then your compiler may have compiled a call to `open` with an old default declaration. This resulted in a call which passed only one argument. The actual open requires at least two arguments. So it received uncontrolled data for the second argument. That might have resulted in opening the file in some undesired mode. Or it might have corrupted your program’s call stack. The behavior of calling a routine with a declaration not matching its definition is not defined by the C or Unix standards. Your program is broken. Fix it. I showed you a correct call.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I did that. still not getting alternate characters.

Comment: @ShantanuShinde please post a [mcve] (that is the exact code you compile). What is your platform and compiler? Also show a minimal input file and the expected output.

Comment: Update the code in the question to show exactly the code you are using now. Show the exact contents of the input file. (Paste them into the question, but also use the `xxd` command to show the contents and paste its output in the question.) Show the exact output of the program. (Again, paste the output into the question, but also redirect the output to a file and use `xxd` to show the contents of that file, and paste it into the question.)

Comment: @Jabberwocky I am using cygwin gcc compiler

Comment: @ShantanuShinde also compile with `-Wall` and treat the warnings as errors.

Comment: @ShantanuShinde oh and please let us know what you mean by _"alternate characters"_

Comment: @EricPostpischil I didn't understood what you told. Doesn't xxd create hex dump file? what should I do of it?

Comment: @ShantanuShinde we want you to show the output of `xxd`. [Edit]  your question and put all clarifications _there_.

Comment: @Jabberwocky alternate = "every other".  Hence the `lseek(fd,1,SEEK_CUR);` calls to skip a character.  Of course, there's no checking should the `lseek()` call hits EOF.

Comment: this should work with removing lseek(fd,1,SEEK_CUR); this seek is making 1 byte skip. please refer man page of read() it is clearly mentioned that if the file support seek then it will auto increment the offset to read in next call.

Comment: @Deepak I want to skip 1 character

Comment: @Shantanu Shinde: sorry for misunderstanding. this function is working fine for me. only extra i have done is as already mentioned by others open the file as:  open(argv[1], O_RDWR);

Comment: @Deepak Mine is skipping the first line as I have posted in the question.

Comment: @Shantanu Shinde: I think this seems some problem how you have saved in input file. i used gvim to copy the same line given by you above and it is printing all the line properly. by skipping properly as:
aceg
jlnp
suwy, all three and in 3 line as there is new line character

Answer (score 4):

You need to `#include <fcntl.h>`, but that's not the actual problem.

The output

```
ikmoq
suwy
```

is actually expected.

The input file

```
abcdefgh
ijklmnopq
rstuvwxyz
```

Looks like this in memory `abcdefgh\r\nijklmnopq\r\nrstuvwxyz`, because under Windows line endings are represendted by "\r\n" two bytes 13 and 10.

You are printing every second character, so you print:

'a' 'c' 'e' 'g' '\r' 'i' 'k' etc.

But as you do raw output with `write`, the `\r` puts just the cursor at the beginning of the line and thus subsequent characters will overwrite the already printed characters.

Change your program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  int fd = open("input.txt", O_RDONLY);

  if (fd > 0)
  {
    char content[1];

    while (read(fd, content, 1))
    {      
      if (content[0] == '\r')
      {
        static char cr[] = "<CR>";
        write(1, cr, sizeof cr - 1);
      }
      else if (content[0] == '\n')
      {
        static char lf[] = "<LF>";
        write(1, lf, sizeof lf - 1);
      }

      else
      {
        write(1, content, 1);
        lseek(fd, 1, SEEK_CUR);
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    printf("File could not be opened.\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This shows what bytes are actually read from the file.

Output:

```
aceg<LF><CR>ikmoq<CR>rtvxz
```

Simplified version of the while loop using `putc` which deals automatically with line endings:

```
while (read(fd, content, 1))
{
  putc(content[0], stdout);
  lseek(fd, 1, SEEK_CUR);
}
```

Version using only system calls (this is probably platform dependant):

```
while (read(fd, content, 1))
{
  if (content[0] == '\r' || content[0] == '\n')
  {
    static char eol[] = "\r\n";
    write(1, eol, sizeof eol - 1);
  }
  else
  {
    write(1, content, 1);
  }

  lseek(fd, 1, SEEK_CUR);
}
```

Comment: How to avoid printing that <LF> and <CR> ?

Comment: @ShantanuShinde This program is for illustration purposes to show what bytes are actually read from the file. If you don't want to print out these special characters, you need to skip (ignore them). Modifying the code in the answer shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: so if I don't write '\r\n' how do I print each line on seperate line?

Comment: @ShantanuShinde I don't have the same platform as you so I'm not sure, please show the output the code in my answer displays on your computer, then I can tell you. Otherwise don't use raw output but use functions from `<stdio.h>` such as `putc`, `printf` etc. which will deal automatically with special characters

Comment: @ShantanuShinde I edited my answer, look at the end.

Comment: actually I have to use write, not any library functions. just system calls.

Comment: I used this: `while(read(fd,content,1))
        {
            if(content[0]!='\r')//&&content[0]!='\n')
            {   
                write(1,content,1);
                lseek(fd,1,SEEK_CUR);
            }
        }` It is working now.

Comment: I think I get why \n is working but \r not. cygwin uses POSIX API, and posix has \n as newline but .txt file has \r\n as newline. I think \r\n will not work with cygwin. so please add my code for that third code block and I will select it as answer.